# How to import a csv file into a mysql table and auto increment

Tags: mysql, csv, mysqlimport

I'm trying to import a csv file into mysql with the following command:

```
mysqlimport --columns=name,amount,desc --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --verbose --local -u muser -p mydb file.csv
```

The file contains fields but not a primary key.  It looks like this:

```
name, amount, desc
```

My mysql table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `organization` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
```

How can I use `mysqlimport` in order to import the csv file and generate the auto-incremented Ids?

When I run this, I get the following error:

> mysqlimport: Error: 1467, Failed to read auto-increment value from
>   storage engine, when using table: organization

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [--columns parameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html#option_mysqlimport_columns) to specify mapping of the fields. The order of the column names indicates how to match data file columns with table columns.

```
mysqlimport --columns=name,amount,desc...
```

Answer (score 5):

expand your csv with a leading empty field:

```
id,name,amount,desc
,john,10,xz
,paul,20,ac
```

Comment: That would work, but I have millions of rows and I wouldn't be able to modify the csv.

Comment: But that was no infomration you provided and no reason to downvote a propper solution for the given problem. For others this might be a helpfull quickfix... downvoting only it doesn´t fit your personal (and not communicated) needs is not fair.

Comment: You can edit the csv on microsoft excel with a few clicks you can add a blank column for all entries

Comment: This worked beautifully for me!  The auto increment fills in the empty column automatically.  And it's trivial to create an empty column (with whatever header you want) when editing a CSV file with Excel.

Answer (score 2):

For those using the phpmyadmin UI to import and/or your table might have a very large number of columns and you don't want to import via a long and tedious sql statement do the following;

1. Use any spreadsheet editor like microsoft excel to add a blank column where the ID column would be.
2. If you get an "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'id' at row 1" error fill in the blank ids you created with 0s, they will be auto incremented on insert.

NB When editing a csv file with a spreadsheet editor just cross check if all columns especially dates or money columns are not formated to the editor's defaults which might be different from your original formats.

Comment: Thank you for saving me from having to write a script! Can't believe I didn't already know this! :P

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this, when importing the CSV file to MYSQL tick the checkbox that says (Update data when duplicate keys found on import (add ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE))
As shown in the screenshot
[MYSQL import data page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHNsf.png)